# DatePicker does not show the text

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have created both a `DatePicker` and a `TimePicker`, but what I see is only the underlining, while the text always appears transparent, I cannot read it. It is still clickable but not readable

```
  <yummy:PancakeView x:Name="CreatePageDiary" IsVisible="False" Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="15,15,0,0" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Green" Grid.Row="1"/>

            <Grid Margin="15" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <BoxView CornerRadius="100" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalOptions="End" WidthRequest="40">
                    <BoxView.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush  StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset="1.0" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </BoxView.Background>
                </BoxView>
                <BoxView x:Name="BVGrayDiary" CornerRadius="100" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalOptions="End" WidthRequest="40" BackgroundColor="Gray"/>
                <Image Source="checked.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"  Grid.Column="4" HorizontalOptions="End" HeightRequest="20" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                <Button x:Name="BTSaveDiary" IsVisible="False" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalOptions="End" HeightRequest="25" Clicked="BTSaveDiary_Clicked"/>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="Transparent" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="calendardataPicker"/>
                    <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" x:Name="DataPicker" TextColor="Blue"/>
                    <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" x:Name="DataPickerVisual" Visual="Material" Opacity="0"/>
                </Grid>


                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Image  Source="clockTimePicker"/>
                        <TimePicker  x:Name="TimePicker" TextColor="Blue"/>
                </StackLayout>
//other code
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but what I see is only the underlining, while the text always appears transparent, I cannot read it. It is still clickable but not readable.

From your screenshot, I guess that you set the same color for contentpage's backgroundcolor and DatePicker and TimePicker TextColor, so you can not see the text.

Don't see TextColor or set other color for DatePicker and TimePicker.

```
 <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Green">
        <DatePicker TextColor="Red"></DatePicker>
        <TimePicker TextColor="Red"></TimePicker>
    </StackLayout>
```

### Update

From your code, I don't have **yummy:PancakeView**, so I use frame to replace **yummy:PancakeView**.

Please set the second Grid RowDefinition Height="Auto" or higher, then DatePicker and TimePicker will display correctly.

```
 <Frame
            x:Name="CreatePageDiary"
            CornerRadius="15"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <BoxView Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Blue" />
                <BoxView Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Green" />

                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <BoxView
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        Grid.Column="4"
                        CornerRadius="100"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        WidthRequest="40">
                        <BoxView.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Blue" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="LightBlue" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </BoxView.Background>
                    </BoxView>
                    <BoxView
                        x:Name="BVGrayDiary"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        Grid.Column="4"
                        BackgroundColor="Gray"
                        CornerRadius="100"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        WidthRequest="40" />
                    <Image
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        Grid.Column="4"
                        Margin="0,0,10,0"
                        HeightRequest="20"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        Source="check.png" />
                    <Button
                        x:Name="BTSaveDiary"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        Grid.Column="4"
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                        HeightRequest="25"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        Text="test" />

                    <Grid
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="favorite.png" />
                        <DatePicker
                            x:Name="DataPicker"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Date="06/21/2018"
                            TextColor="Blue" />
                        <DatePicker
                            x:Name="DataPickerVisual"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            Visual="Material" />
                    </Grid>


                    <StackLayout
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="favorite.png" />
                        <TimePicker x:Name="TimePicker" TextColor="Blue" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
```

The screen that I test:

[image]

Comment: I need a Grid, not a stackLayout, but although I have the page background of one color and set the TextColor property of Blue, I still see everything transparent

Comment: @signalover Please provide more code about your contentpage.

Comment: I have updated the code. I don't understand where I'm wrong

Comment: I simply had the Row too small in size and couldn't see it